# Detect high load from within Play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way from within Play to know whether it is currently under high load, means it can't respond to every request?

Answer (score 0):

Using a library like [Sigar](http://sigar.hyperic.com/), you could measure system's load average or memory consumption. But that's for all the system. Not only for your particular application.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice tool, but I'd like to do from within Play.

Comment: Sigar is a library, not a tool. You can use it within Play.